get parent SKU - variable product with bundles
On woocommerce I have a variable product (A). inside there are 2 variants (X and Y). These 2 variants are made up of a bundle of products. During the purchase and order phase, I always see the SKU of the chosen variant (X or Y). I instead need the sku of the parent product (A). I would like this to be the main one and for it to be within the order.
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_get_sku', 'custom_order_item_sku', 10, 2);
function custom_order_item_sku($sku, $item) {

$product_id = $item->get_product_id();

// Ottieni il prodotto
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Controlla se il prodotto è una variante
if ($product && $product->is_type('variation')) {
    // Ottieni l'ID del prodotto padre
    $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($product_id);
    
    // Ottieni il prodotto padre
    $parent_product = wc_get_product($parent_id);
    
    // Restituisci lo SKU del prodotto padre
    if ($parent_product) {
        return $parent_product->get_sku();
    }
}

// Restituisci lo SKU originale se non è una variante
return $sku;
}

